# If $a|b$ and $b\ne0$, then $|a|\le |b|$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am trying to understand and show this statement.

> If $a|b$ and $b\ne0$, then $|a|\le |b|$.

Since $a|b$, a number $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ exists such that $ak=b$. What is next? How to show the statement?

Comment: Nope! I didn' t down-vote your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly $k\ne 0$ so $|k|\geq 1$ so $$|b|=|ak|=|a||k|\geq |a|\cdot 1 = |a|$$

Comment: But how $ak=b$ is the same as $|ak|=|b|$? I haven't seen this before.

Comment: If $x=y$ then $|x| = |y|$. Is that true?

Comment: Yep, it's true.

Comment: @Ak19, oh please. I hate 'obvious' in maths. If something is "obvious" for you, DOES NOT mean it is obvious for me or someone else.

Comment: @NikolDimitrova I'm sorry!

Comment: You shouldn't be. Thank you, Aqua! You're brilliant! And I guess you (@Ak19) are the one who voted down my post. What exactly do I need to clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Assume they are both positive (if not, we can multiply by -1 on one of the sides and the property should still hold). What restrictions lie on $k$? Then what happens if you subtract $k$ from both sides? How many times will you need to do this to reach $0=0$?

Comment: We do not have restrictions on $k\in\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: k must be a positive integer, right? What properties do all positive integers have?

Comment: No, $k$ can also be a negative integer! $13|-1001$ because $13.(-77)=-1001$ and here $k=-77$.

Comment: Sorry, i meant on absolute value of k... Aqua's answer is better

Comment: OK, fixed answer, sorry about that